# python lxml insert namespaces into header

Tags: python, xml

I am creating an xml file and I would like to insert namespaces into header. I want to get this.

```
<ns2:prenosPodatkovRazporedaOdgovorSporocilo xmlns="http://someurl" xmlns:ns2="http://someotherurl" xmlns:ns3="http://another_someotherurl">
<ns2:statusPrenosa>
  <status>09</status>
  <nazivStatusa>Napaka prenosa</nazivStatusa>
```

while I get this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<prenosPodatkovRazporedaOdgovorSporocilo>
  <ns0:podatkiRazporeda xmlns:ns0="ns2">
    <ns2:podatkiRazporeda xmlns:ns2="ns3">
.....
```

register_namespace does not do the trick or how do I include them when using tostring() function

```
etree.register_namespace('n2',"http://someurl")
etree.register_namespace('n3',"http://someother_url")
etree.register_namespace('n4',"http://another_someotherurl")
```

hope I was clear enough

thank you

Comment: Do you set `etree.nsmap` accordingly?

Comment: Did you try `lxml.etree.tostring(t, inclusive_ns_prefixes=True)`?

Comment: @Yebach If you mean that those namespaces are not in the original XML and you want to add them, then you can't just use `register_namespace`...

Comment: @Alfe adding nsmap = {...} solved the problem - thank you

Comment: I realized that ns numbers are increasing trough structure-  which I do not want so I have ` <ns54:organizacijskaEnota> ` - where is the catch??